# Dualboot mint and windows 10 - Could not create a variable. Out or Resources

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot

sda1 - Windows efi,
sda4 - Mint efi (as second installed)

For some time now, the laptop turns on when power is applied (even though this option in UEFI is disabled). Since two days UEFI doesn't save changes, switching from Mint to Windows forces time synchronization. Is this related to my problem?

I used grub reinstall commands described in this link, the most upvoted answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition

Normally when I am booting get the message "Could not create a variable. Out or Resources", after a few seconds Mint loads. I can only get to Windows via F9 -> OS Boot Manager, bootmgfw.efi.mui does not boot.

Boot from EFI File => Partition 4 => ubuntu => grubx64.efi does not throw up grub, but after a few seconds of a grey screen Mint boots or or I have to restart my computer

What should I do in this case?

[Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QesXl.jpg)

Comment: While UEFI standard allows multiple ESP - efi system partitions, most UEFI do not work with multiple esp per drive. Remove one ESP and reinstall grub (or Windows) totally to use new ESP. You may need to first edit fstab, with correct UUID for ESP you keep.  have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware. Many systems need that also. What brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Comment: @oldfred With two efi partitions the grub ran for two months. Last Saturday I went into mint for a while, installed a 500 MB update and it stopped working.

I didn't update the UEFI (it's BIOS, but set to UEFI without CSM) or the disk firmware (you mean from within the BIOS?).

it's HP Probook 6570b with integrated HD 4000
BIOS: 68ICE ver. F.06 08/03/2012 (i see on hp site there is newest F.74 from May 2019)
Intel GOP Driver 1.0.4.1002

Comment: I would make sure backups are good & update UEFI firmware. Big jump from F.06 to F.74.